# new DateTime changing the time

Tags: jodatime

DateTime now = new DateTime(time, tz);

time = 2019-08-22T07:50:00.000Z

tz = America/Chicago

now = 2019-08-22T02:50:00.000-05:00

This is happening on the build server causing the unit tests to fail. Tests pass on my machine. Why is the time getting changed ?

Comment: Your example only shows the change of LOCAL time, but there is no change in the moment/instant aka "time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because I instantiated `time` without a time zone. So when instantiated `now` with chicago timezone, it was assuming `time` is GMT and subtracted 5 from time. It was fixed after I specified timezone for `time`.